# How to return Multiple Model values from a single Method Controller?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

```
  public partial class Person
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; } 
    }

  public partial class Account
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Pass { get; set; } 
    }
```

And my `getDetails` controller  like this. It's mean create a model `DetailsAndAcount` include `Account` and `Person`

```
public class DetailsAndAcount {
       public List<Account> acc {get; set;}
       public Person person {get; set;}
}

public ActionResult UserDeltails(string ID) {
    var accList = new List<Account>();
    var personList  = new Person();
    var detailsAndAcount  = new DetailsAndAcount ();
    ....
    accList= db.Accounts.Where(c => c.ID == ID).ToList();
    personList = db.Persons.Where(c => c.ID== ID).First();
    return View();
}
```

I want return list `detailsAndAcount` (from `DetailsAndAcount` model) include `accList` (`DetailsAndAcount` model) and `personList` (`Person` model)  from `UserDeltails` method.

How can I do that?

Comment: `detailsAndAccount.acc = accList; detailsAndAccount.person = personList; ereturn View(detailsAndAccount);`?

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there, if you want to use the model in your view use you gotta give that to your view like this.

```cs
public class DetailsAndAcount {
       public List<Account> acc {get; set;}
       public Person person {get; set;}
}

public ActionResult UserDeltails(string ID) {
    var accList = new List<Account>();
    var personList  = new Person();
    var detailsAndAcount  = new DetailsAndAcount ();
    ....
    detailsAndAcount.acc = db.Accounts.Where(c => c.ID == ID).ToList();
    detailsAndAcount.person = db.Persons.Where(c => c.ID== ID).First();
    return View(detailsAndAcount);
}
```

Also make sure to get your namings correctly, if something is a collection give it a name in plural.

Comment: I tried your solution before. In the view, I tried `@model NameSpace.Controllers.UserDeltailsController.DetailsAndAcount ` but it not work.

Comment: I got `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`  when I try `@foreach (var item in Model.acc)`

Comment: Are u sure you're getting data out of the linq query ?